# How to imbricate a QApplication inside a main QApplication

Tags: python, qt, qtgui, gnuradio

I'm currently working on a GUI interface that runs a [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org) script rendering some Qt windows (plotting real time histogramm, waterfall graph, or other nice gui...). I control its parameters and launch it from my first main windows. I'd like to integrate the QApp created by launching the GNU Radio script inside a widget of my first main windows (which is another QApp).

I already tried to run a second QApp in the same time of my first one, for some reasons, I get errors like `QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread`.

I did not work around this error because a nicer idea would be to have a kind of container whom I would give a `PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication` object to make him execute and display it without creating a second windows.

Does that kind of container exist ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You cannot have more than one QApplication object per process. I think the best of your options is to fork GNU Radio and integrate your GUI with it at source code level.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: no, don't do that. GNU Radio companion (which OP probably uses) just creates a python file which instantiates the QApplication iff the file is run as executable, and then shows the window in that context. You can simply use the module in your own code.